# What is the termonology for an array with a strictly defined structure?

Tags: arrays

If one has an array with a strictly defined structure, what is this called? For example every first element must be name, second must be color, third must be price. The array would look something like...

```
var cars = [
    "civic",
    "red",
    "8000",

    "escort",
    "blue",
    "6000"
];
```

Comment: Wrong. The terminology for such an array is wrong.

Comment: I don't think there is a term for this specifically, it sounds like what you want is a dictionary for this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no term aside from 'array' or 'data structure'.

You could think of this as an array of 'structs' or 'objects' but that would imply some sort of enforceable mechanic to keep the data valid.

Note: Please don't store any data in this format. You are asking for trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on why it looks like that. If you consider it a 2D array representing a table, it's just that: A 2D array implemented in a 1D array.